# How can I design a clean system using 120 v generator, battery back UPS, and a reversed transformer to get a clean stable 220v with 30 amps?

Tags: transformer, generator

This is a old question about design and I must of asked the wrong question. so here goes.
Do I even need the Battery backup in this design and how does it affect the volts and total amps? looking to get 30 amps or better.
Below is what was discussed previously.

I have a [Westinghouse 3600W 30 ampere 120 volt generator.](https://westinghouseoutdoorpower.com/products/wgen3600v-generator-stationary)

Can I run it through a battery backup UPS to keep the volts stable, then use an [HS1F2AS isolation transformer](http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/1845858.pdf) wired backwards to get 240 volts to the breaker box?

This would allow me to run the 240V well pump and maybe the 240V hot water heater.

I am trying to use what I materials I have on hand.

The manufacturer said the transformer can be wired backwards, but I haven't got a clue how to. I'm going to add a breaker and use an interlock to stop the generator from powering the utility lines to the house.

If any one has an idea, please tell me.

---

This is a picture of the transformer nameplate:

[image]

Comment: The part I don't understand is the wiring in the transformer. the spec data sheet is different than the actual item...HS1F2AS........... https://www.ebay.com/itm/HEVI-DUTY-HS1F2AS-TRANSFORMER-240-480V-60HZ-1PH-2-0KVA-120-240V-TYPE-HS-XLNT/182491709384

Comment: Add details to the question, don't dribble them out in various comments.

Answer (score 1):

First you find find your transformer in the table on page 225:

[image]

Then, you look at the column headers:

[image]

For the column "Elec Conn*" (electrical connection,) your transformer has "16."

You refer to electrical connection diagram number 16 on page 230:

[image]

"Running a transformer in reverse" means you swap the primary and secondary sides.

You wire it just like if you were going to use it normally, but you provide power on the secondary instead of the primary.

In your case, you want the primary to be 240V and the secondary to be 120V.

You wire H1 to H3, then H2 to H4.

Your 240V comes out of H1 and H4.

You wire X1 to X3 then X2 to X4.

You connect your 120V from the generator to X1 and X4.

---

If diagram 16 doesn't match your transformer, then you have a different model than you've named.  Make sure you have the correct transformer model and the correct electrical connection diagram.

Go by the model number marked on the transformer, not by what the seller told you on e-bay.

If the transformer isn't marked, ask the manufacturer how you can properly identify which tranformer you have

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/169kRSS   This is a picture of my transformer.

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/1RIXUeO.jpg this it my transformer

Comment: Sorry I don't know how to post a picture, I hope the link works

Comment: @JuniorHarvell:  I put the picture in your question where it belongs.  It is an HS1F2AS, so diagram 16 should be correct.  It also matches what's on the nameplate.

Answer (score 0):

If the manufacturer says it’s ok to run the autotransformer backwards then it’s ok in principle.  There will be one common terminal between the 120 and 230v, this should be neutral.  Then your generator phase connects to the 120v terminal and 230v phase will be output.  It seems from the question that you’re clear that the output must never be connected to the mains supply.  Whether it’s ok to leave the neutral connected and just switch over the phase depends on your local laws, I’m not qualified to comment on that aspect.

Comment: The part I don't understand is the wiring in the transformer. the spec data sheet is different from the actual item...HS1F2AS....that I have. Here is a link to a transformer like the one I have. I understand basic wiring, from the generator there is black(live)white(neutral) green(ground)  at the breaker box red and black(live) white(neutral) copper(ground) I need to know what wires the generator connects to and what wires from the transformer connects to. H1,2,3,4 and X1,2,3,4   https://www.ebay.com/itm/HEVI-DUTY-HS1F2AS-TRANSFORMER-240-480V-60HZ-1PH-2-0KVA-120-240V-TYPE-HS-XLNT/182491709384

Comment: @Frog,  It's an isolation transformer not an autotransformer

Comment: My bad, should have read the question